# meta_query with multiple values

Tags: meta-query

I need your help.

There is my problem: I have custom post type "Player". And this *CPT* has custom field "Seasons". Seasons can have multiple values separated by comma - for example "2014,2015,2016" etc.

Now I need filter list of player who played in certain seasons - for example 2015 and 2016.

And now I need your help with this `wp_query`. I try this code, but it do not work :-/

```
query_posts(
    array(

        'post_type' => 'player',
        'meta_query' => array(

            array(
                'key'     => 'seasons',
                'value'   => array( '2015','2016'),
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ),

        ),

    )

);
```

Please help.

Thanks, 
libor

Answer (score 5):

Expanding a bit on the answer from @dgarceran

Generally, using the `WP_Query` class is probably a good idea for querying posts.

We'll want to pass arguments to that query.

In your case we'll likely want use one of the following:

1. "**Custom Field Parameters**" - `meta_query`
2. "**Taxonomy Parameters**" - `tax_query`

For a nearly comprehensive example of all the options I like to reference this gist: https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628.

Also see the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Both take an array of associative arrays e.g.

**Note**: I'll be using syntax that is compatible with as of PHP 5.4

```
    $meta_query_args = [
        [
            'key'     => 'season',
            'value'   => [ '2015', '2016' ],
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ],
    ];
```

We can bring those arguments into our instance of `WP_Query`

```
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'player',
        'posts_per_page' => 100, // Set this to a reasonable limit
        'meta_query'     => $meta_query_args,

    ];

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What's happenning at this point is WordPress is going to check all posts that match your **custom post type** `player`. Then, it will query the metadata you've set with key `season`. Any posts matching `2015` or `2016` will be returned.

**Note:** using `meta_query` this way isn't generally recommended because it's a little heavy on the database. The consensus seems to be that querying taxonomies is more performant (don't quote me on that, couldn't find my source)

So for a quick alternative, I reccomend the following example:

```
    $tax_query_args = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'season',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ '2015', '2016' ],
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ],
    ];

    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'player',
        'posts_per_page' => 100, // Set this to a reasonable limit
        'tax_query'      => $tax_query_args,
    ];

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Now we can actually loop through the data, here's some example markup:

```
        <section class="season-list">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                // $season  = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'season', true ); // example if you are still going to use post meta
                $season = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'season', [ 'fields' => 'names' ] );
                ?>

                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo __( 'Season: ' ) . sanitize_text_field( implode( $season ) ); ?></p>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </section>
```

When you use `WP_Query` especially in templates, make sure you end with `wp_reset_postdata();`

Putting it altogether (tl;dr)

```
    $tax_query_args = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'season',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ '2015', '2016' ],
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ],
    ];

    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'player',
        'posts_per_page' => 100, // Set this to a reasonable limit
        'tax_query'      => $tax_query_args,
    ];

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>
        <section class="season-list">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                // $season  = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'season', true ); // example if you are still going to use post meta
                $season = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'season', [ 'fields' => 'names' ] );
                ?>

                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo __( 'Season: ' ) . sanitize_text_field( implode( $season ) ); ?></p>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </section>
    <?php

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Front-end view of our query:**
[image: Example Front End]
**Dashboard view of CPT Player posts:**
[image: Example CPT Player posts]

Hope that provides a bit of context

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it with [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and using [Codex examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'player',
    'meta_key'   => 'age',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'seasons',
            'value'   => array( 2015, 2016 ), // or array( '2015', '2016' )
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Your problem is that you're adding values in one string like "2015,2016,2017"... and you should separate every value in a different field. With [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) you have the option of adding a repeater of seasons, and you can also do a [custom taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) to save these values, instead than a post meta. If you don't want to change that, you should retrieve your post meta data first with [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), and use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with PHP.

Comment: ok, thx fo reply...

how can i do it with post meta? how can i get first get_post_meta in meta_query? i dont get it ...