# meta_query with multiple values optimization

Tags: meta-query

I need your help with multiple values in meta_query. I have a checkbox filter. This is the query I came up:

But, I'm worried that query is not optimized, and that it will slow down the site.

I read the solution asked in this question:
[meta_query with multiple values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250147/meta-query-with-multiple-values)
But, when I implement that solution I have the following error:
"***Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string***".

Is there any way how to optimize this query?

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post' ,
    'meta_key'       => $meta_value,
    'orderby'        => $sort . ' date',
    'order'          => $order_sort,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat'            => $category,
    'paged'          => $paged,

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'checkboxes',
            'value' => $face,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'checkboxes',
            'value' => $twitter,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'checkboxes',
            'value' => $telegram,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'checkboxes',
            'value' => $reddit,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'checkboxes',
            'value' => $email,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'checkboxes',
            'value' => $phone,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Where are the variables you’re using for value coming from? $face, $reddit etc.

Comment: They are coming from the checkbox click. With Advanced Custom Fields plugin, I have added field type checkbox for the post. If user click on the checkbox in example for the facebook, field `$face = 'facebook`'.

Comment: No, I mean where are you setting the value of the variables. Variables don't set themselves. Where in your code are you setting `$face = `.

Comment: Here is the code for setting the variable `$face` `if ( isset($_GET['f']) && $_GET['f'] == '1')  {$face='"facebook"';}`

Comment: So if `$_GET['f']` isn't set then `$face` isn't set. This is probably why you're getting the error.

Comment: it is set, I gave it some string, so that it is not empty. Error is not because that. I tried adding multiple values, just like it is explained in that question, without my variable and I still get that error.

Answer (score 2):

Post meta data was never designed to be used efficiently in queries. Using it with `LIKE` based matching will only make it more horrible.

You need to rethink your DB. For example use taxonomy terms to indicate which social network is associated with a post.

Answer (score 1):

Without some other info it's pretty tough to give any solution to your this above issue. But it seems like your `$face`, `$twitter`, `$telegram` etc. data are coming in a form of `object` or other datatype(not `array` or `string`). But `meta_query`'s `value` only accepts `string` and `array`. So, based on this assumption I would suggest you to make sure that all those data of yours should be a ***one dimensional*** `array` of the values you want to filter or simple `string`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the reply. Data from the `$face`, `$twitter` etc are coming from the checkbox click. If checkbox is checked `$face = 'facebook'`.