# meta_query array in 'values' returns an error

Tags: meta-query

I want to add multiple values in the meta_query. I found the soulution in this link:

[meta_query with multiple values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250147/meta-query-with-multiple-values)

Here is the code:

```
$meta_query_args = [
    [
        'key' => 'checkboxes',
        'value' => [ '"facebook"', '"twitter"' ],
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ],
];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post' ,
    'meta_key' => $meta_value,
    'orderby' => $sort . ' date',
    'order' => $order_sort,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat' => $category,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query_args,   

);
```

But I have the following error:

**Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...**

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` as a compare value doesn't make sense with an array. You want `compare` to be `IN`. Also, you've got an extra set of quotes in the `values` for no reason:

```
$meta_query_args = [
    [
        'key'     => 'checkboxes',
        'value'   => ['facebook', 'twitter'],
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ],
];
```

EDIT: So, according to your comment you're using ACF, which stores multiple checkboxes as a serialized array. Therefore you need to use multiple LIKE queries on individual strings.

```
$meta_query_args = [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    [
        'key'     => 'checkboxes',
        'value'   => '"facebook"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ],
    [
        'key'     => 'checkboxes',
        'value'   => '"twitter"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ],
];
```

Your mistake was trying to use an array as a value with LIKE. To query LIKE multiple possible values you need multiple meta queries with the `OR` relation. The extra quotes are because it's the only way to really query a specific value within a serialized array.

The meta value for `checkboxes` if Facebook and Twitter were checked would look something like this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:8:"facebook";i:1;s:7:"twitter";}
```

So when you query `LIKE` `'"facebook"` you're trying to find the value `"facebook"` within a full value like that. The quotes are to make sure you don't incorrectly find a value like `not_facebook`.

If you have a lot of values that you need to query this way then your performance is going to be awful. This is a very inefficient way to store data for this type of query.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm using [ACF checkbox fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/) for that key. With your suggestion there is no error, but no results also.

Comment: I've updated my answer. ACF stores multiple checkboxes in a specific way that requires a different approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And you are on top with every suggestion. In my original code I'm doing the way you have suggested. I have 6 options in checkbox, so that would be 6 arrays in meta_query. And I'm very concerned if it will slow down my site.

Comment: Yes 6 LIKE queries in a meta query is almost certainly going to have terrible performance. Have you considered a taxonomy?

Comment: Yes, I have read that it is best to use taxonomy in this case, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case.

Comment: thank you. I have created custom taxonomy and change my query.